# Why calender control always show the time as 12:00:00 AM on any date if you print the whole date?

Tags: .net, asp.net, datetime, calendar

When i print the selected date on `Calendar1_SelectionChanged` event it prints: `1/29/2011 12:00:00 AM`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because a DateTime always comes with a date and a time. A calendar control only produces a date, but since you can't have a DateTime without a time part, it just sets the time to 00:00:00. You can ignore the time part.

If you want to print the date without the meaningless time part, use the `ToShortDateString` method or something similar.

Comment: Or one of the many different formats accepted by String.Format() for DateTime.

Comment: Hence the "something similar". There's a dozen ways to turn a date into a string, and I didn't feel like listing all of them.